# Copy Specific cells and paste in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a column 'A'(About 10 rows) with a drop down option in cell. I want copy the data and paste in another sheet and here i want ignore a cell contains "Please Select" in column A. Please help me with VBA code to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome @Arun Kumar

Manual approach might me easiest. Use a filter, selecting the "Text Filters" option and then "Does not equal" and type "Please select" in the form. Now copy and paste to the new spreadsheet.

If you really need to do this with VBA, I suggest you record the above with the "record a macro" option op the developer ribbon. This will generate the required VBA code which you can modify as required.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am aware of manual work, but i need a VBA code solve the issue. What happens when record a macro my requirement doesn't work due i have to unselect specific word in autofilters.

Comment: Record a clear filter command with your macro, then a "does not equal filter" "any keyword here". Now inspect the code and replace that keyword will a cell reference. Your keyword is now a variable. You can type anything in the cell then run the macro. You can also make the cell a dropdown list (data > data validation) of all the available keywords using the UNIQUE function in Office 365.